# substitute with modified matched with :s

Tags: substitute

I want to change :

```
int i = libfnc1();
float j = libfnc2();
libfnc3();
```

to

```
int i = lib::libfnc1();
float j = lib::libfnc2();
lib::libfnc3();
```

using :s

I want to do somthing like `:s/libfnc[0-9]/lib::**MATCHED**/g` but I haven't found what to put in place of **MATCHED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `&` or `\0` for this:

```
:%s/libfnc[0-9]/lib::&/g
```

See [`:help sub-replace-special`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special) for more details.

An alternative approach is to exclude the `libfnc...` part from the match, by [ending the match with `\ze`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5Cze):

```
:%s/\zelibfnc[0-9]/lib::/g
```

This will search for the entire expression `libfnc[0-9]` but will only include the part *before* the `\ze` (in this case, nothing) in the replacement.

Comment: neither work `:%s/libfnc[0-9]/lib::&/g` just replaces the `libfncX` by `lib::&` so I think it's related to my dev environment (vim plugin for visual sutdio code)

Comment: If you're talking about VSCodeVim then yes, it looks like that doesn't support this feature. Not sure what to suggest about that, sorry. Maybe try editing in Vim! ;)